# Graphene-Python + Private Azure Functions?

Tags: python, azure, graphql, azure-functions, graphene-python

**Context:** I'm in the process of designing an event-driven Python application. Various stakeholders have tasked me with investigating options for deploying the application using GraphQL endpoints within a serverless environment running on Azure Functions. End goal being that as the underlying data structures grow, we'd like to easily maintain the use-ability and performance of the application over time. Based on below resources it appears this is possible:

(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/build-2019-build-scalable-apis-using-graphql-and-serverless/)
(https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/videos/azure-friday-live-building-serverless-python-apps-with-azure-functions/)
(https://graphene-python.org/)

**Question:** User requirements dictate that the Azure Functions MUST be for internal use only and cannot be exposed publicly. Reading through the docs below I haven't found any resources on security config options for private endpoints.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/
[Private endpoint in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58390218/private-endpoint-in-azure)

Can someone please point me in the right direction? Are Azure Functions even capable of this? And if they aren't can this be achieved with an alternative like Azure App Service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Functions have multiple hosting options including [Consumption Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#consumption-plan), [Premium Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#premium-plan) and [App Service Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale#app-service-plan).

Out of which, for complete VNET Isolation, [App Service Environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/intro) is the only way to go as of now since the [Private Endpoints for Azure Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/networking/private-endpoint) is currently in preview.

**But** note that [Azure Functions can be deployed into a Kubernetes cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-kubernetes-keda) as well which could be the better option if you already have a kubernetes cluster to deploy to.